# R word cloud visual in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

Trying to get Tableau to display a simple R visual (word cloud) but I can't get it work. Any help would be appreciated.

R code:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
cp <- Corpus(VectorSource('asdf gato perro 98945')) 
wordcloud(cp)
```

The table calculation in Tableau looks like this:

```
SCRIPT_STR("library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
cp <- Corpus(VectorSource('asdf gfg ff 98945')) 
wordcloud(cp)",ATTR([SampleMeasure1]))
```

My question is how can I display the above word cloud without supplying a measure (SampleMeasure1)? Is it even possible to display an R word cloud in Tableau? If so could anyone please provide a simple example what the calculation should look like?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your goal is simply to make a word cloud in Tableau from a vector you have in R?

I took the vector you suggested and produced a dataframe with random counts for each string in the vector. I saved the vector as a csv.

```
count <- as.integer(round(runif(4,1,100),0))
words <- c('asdf','gfg','ff','98945')
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(words,count),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$count <- as.integer(df$count)
write.csv(df,"word_cloud.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

Then if I import the csv to Tableau I can simply create a word cloud. The below image shows the Tableau configurations:

- The "Word" needs to be put in the text bin.
- The "Count" should be in the size bin.
- **Then you have to flip the marks drop down menu to text. It will produce a word cloud. **

[image]

Alternatively you can use the wordcloud library as you're attempting to do. I used the Kaggle Starbucks data set for this example, [found here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?sortBy=relevance&group=all&search=starbucks). The code used to generate this image was:

```
library(wordcloud)
df <- read.csv("directory.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
words <- df$City
words <- gsub(" ",".",words)
wordcloud(words, min.freq = 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful. That would be great if you could help get the second option work (display R word cloud as image). I got a dimension in Tableau with all the strings that I'd like to use for the word cloud eventually. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The R code is straightforward. What I couldn't figure out was that how i could get this all displayed in Tableau. The steps I followed:
* Create calculated field
* Selected table calculation
* Selected "SCRIPT_STR"

Not sure how to move on? Rserve is definitely running so that's not the problem. The following error is displayed in Tableau:

The result returned by the SCRIPT function is of an unexpected type.

Comment: @GraveDigger Gotcha, I am not going to be helpful on that because I don't have RServer :(  Sorry about that and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

R: Making a Word Cloud Graph (Words Graph) Simple

Suppose you have one table with words and related values like this one, named Top5
[Top5 sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjFd8.jpg)

In order to get
[example produced by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj0SL.jpg)
Do the following:

1. Import the Top5 dataset
2. Execute:

   install.packages("wordcloud") # word-cloud generator
   `library("wordcloud")`
   `wordcloud(words = Top5$word, freq = Top5$value, min.freq = 1, max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.2,  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))`